# When to use sudo for software installs?

Tags: security, software-installation

I usually use sudo when I install software that would be of "general use" for anyone on the machine. For example,

```
$ sudo apt-get install mailutils
```

I do this because in the past I have had installs fail without sudo. However, I have heard that it can be bad to do this for security reasons and I often see examples (such as the one above) without sudo being used.

How can I determine when software should be installed as the super user?

Comment: apt-get install cannot be used without root privileges, so you should use sudo with it.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I install personal software like all the time without using sudo. I only use sudo when installing general use software.

Comment: How do you use apt without root privileges? Are you talking about apt's source option?

Answer (score 3):

You absolutely have to use sudo to get privileges escalations.
This is needed for any/all installations of software & administration tasks.

But for security reasons, you may understand this is privileged so using it for  doing "normal/ordinary" things is an error..

If you find some examples without sudo it is because if you are already logged as root user, you don't need sudo... you have already the full permissions on the machine.

The only exception to that is installing your own binaries or scripts in the user land environment...  but this is a bad practice ... it should be considered as a third party software... so installed in a subdirectory of /opt for example....

Comment: Ok, so you are saying that this instructional article on the web which has multiple installs with no sudo is incorrect: http://www.binarytides.com/linux-mail-command-examples/

Comment: No, no, it uses apt & yum to install softwares so this will respect packages structures so files will be all installed correctly in /usr sub-directories.  What I say is when you are already logged as root  sudo is useless & second case, if you use your own programs you may install them either with sudo either keep them in userland (but in user-land it is olso recommanded to put files in subdirectories of /opt for example ... or even better build your own packages to install in real conditions using system subdirectories (usually /usr subdirectories)

Comment: I guess I don't understand you. In the article I linked the guy is installing software from the $ prompt, so he is not logged in as root and he is not using sudo. .